# setContentView(); giving error in my splash screen activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, splash-screen

### Hello Android Developers,

I am making an app which runs welcome screen (as app features for only one time as user installs app)and then splash screen which contains logo of my app and then it proceed to app my api level is min 17(jelly bean 4.1) my app runs **full stable** on **android ver. 5.0+** without any error without any problem

---

but when i try to run my app android version like **4.1** or even **4.4.2** it gives me error on
 **setContentView(activity_splash_screen);**
after welcome screen opens it crashes i have tried openign loginscreen after welcome as next intent instead of splashscreen then also it give same error with **setContentView(activity_login_screen);** then i try that if directly make my mainactivivty open after welcomeactivity (skipping splash & login both) then it open main page but without navigation drawer and without toolbar name only first page open

---

my app original sequence
which runs on ver. 5.0+

welcomeactivity-->splashscreen-->login-screen->mainactivity-->full app

---

**error for splash screen after welcome if i open splash screen activity**

```
09-11 00:20:54.072 1798-1798/com.example.pk.testing_app2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.pk.testing_app2, PID: 1798
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pk.testing_app2/com.example.pk.testing_app2.SplashScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2009)
                                                                              at com.example.pk.testing_app2.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:14)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2009) 
                                                                              at com.example.pk.testing_app2.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:14) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/logo.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020060
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3443)
                                                                              at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2009) 
                                                                              at com.example.pk.testing_app2.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:14) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                              at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
                                                                              at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3439)
                                                                              at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133) 
                                                                              at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2009) 
                                                                              at com.example.pk.testing_app2.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:14) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**splash screen activity**

```
  import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;


public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);



        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        }, 1500);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think before find toolbar you should do setcontentview

Comment: have you check your xml file of splashscreen?and post youy full logcat here.

Comment: i have updated  logcat now for splash screen and welcome screen in now opeing only it get crashes for splashsscreen now also :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);` after initialising your toolbar. This probably give you `nullPointerExcaption`.

so best practice is to write `setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);` just after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

**Example :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    // rest of the code..
}
```

Comment: "thanks" i have done that now welcome screen is opring but after that spalsh screen gets crashed on that **setcontetview line** and if i open loginactivity  after welcome then also it crashes on same line **setcontetview of login activity** i have given error for that please look and tell if any solution for that

Comment: error is in your xml file. can you post your xml file of SplashScreenActivity?

Comment: i got solved with problem i think vector images are not supported in lower ver. like below **5.0** i have used .png images  and it working fine thank you for drawing my attention to xml file

Comment: anytime.. you can mark this answer if it helped you. :)